# Navigation Controller not animating in ios5

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios5

I'm using the below code to pop to root view controller:

```
self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES
```

Its working fine, but animation is missing in IOS5(no issue in older version) even then when I passed YES for animation.

Any idea please??

Comment: what is your navigation / view controller structure?

Comment: Do you have your VC inside the tab bar ?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are not calling:
`[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]`
You may have done it somewhere else and forgot to put it back to YES.